# Quarkus Camel file component not working proprely

Tags: kotlin, file, gradle, apache-camel, quarkus

I am actually developing an integration service with **Apache Camel + Quarkus + Kotlin + Gradle**. I'm trying to **read from a file** and copy to other file. Simple.

The code example I'm using a code-with-quarkus, downloaded directly from the Quarkus Camel starter webpage.

Thing is, the [Camel File component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/file-component.html) is giving me some trouble:

I can read a file from its absolute path:

```kotlin
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder

class Route : RouteBuilder() {

  override fun configure() {
      from("file:///Users/john/Downloads/code-with-quarkus/files/input")
          .convertBodyTo(String::class.java)
          .log("${body()}")
      .to("file:///Users/john/Downloads/code-with-quarkus/files/input")
  }
}
```

but **not from the relative path** to the project:

```kotlin
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder

class Route : RouteBuilder() {

  override fun configure() {
      from("file:files/input")
          .convertBodyTo(String::class.java)
          .log("${body()}")
      .to("file:files/output")
  }
}
```

My project folder structure is:

[image: folder structure]

I cannot use the absolute path because it needs to be generic. The files are not empty and when I execute the route, it says that it has started but no error or nothing is printed.

```
2023-03-06 16:03:39,643 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) Apache Camel 3.20.1 (camel-1) is starting
2023-03-06 16:03:39,655 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread) Routes startup (started:1)
2023-03-06 16:03:39,655 INFO  [org.apa.cam.imp.eng.AbstractCamelContext] (Quarkus Main Thread)     Started route1 (file://files/input)
```

Am I pointing to the wrong folder path? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!!

PD: my build.gradle.kt

```kotlin
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    java
    id("io.quarkus")
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.20-Beta"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}

val quarkusPlatformGroupId: String by project
val quarkusPlatformArtifactId: String by project
val quarkusPlatformVersion: String by project

dependencies {
    implementation(
            enforcedPlatform(
                    "${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}"
            )
    )
    implementation(
            enforcedPlatform(
                    "${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:quarkus-camel-bom:${quarkusPlatformVersion}"
            )
    )
    implementation("org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-file")
    implementation("org.apache.camel.quarkus:camel-quarkus-quartz")
    implementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-arc")
    testImplementation("io.quarkus:quarkus-junit5")
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}

group = "org.acme"

version = "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    systemProperty("java.util.logging.manager", "org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager")
}

tasks.withType<JavaCompile> {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    options.compilerArgs.add("-parameters")
}
val compileKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
val compileTestKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileTestKotlin.kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "1.8"
}
```

Comment: If you use a relative path, the path is then related to the user directory, so here I guess that your user directory is not where you expect it. You can use the command `jcmd` to get the process id of your application, then launch `jcmd <process-id> VM.system_properties | grep user.dir`, to get the effective user directory of your application

Comment: Yeah! You were right... I don't know if that is my only perception but Camel sometimes is really hard to understand, and the documentation is not clear. Thank you very much!!